# Duplicate subgoals in Coq

Tags: coq-tactic

Is there some Coq tactic to prevent the generation of several identical subgoals? If not, is it possible to write some tactic for eliminating the duplicate subgoals just after its generation? In Isabelle you can do it with:

```
apply (tactic {* distinct_subgoals_tac *})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to eliminate duplicates after the fact without writing OCaml code, but you can create an evar which is the conjunction of all subgoals, deduplicated.  Something like this:

```
Ltac distinct_subgoals_tactical tac :=
  let H := fresh in
  unshelve epose proof _ as H;
  [ |
  | tac;
    [ (* first split apart the hypothesis containing the conjunction of all previous subgoals *)
      repeat match type of H with prod _ _ => destruct H as [? H] end;
      (* see if any of them solve the goal *)
      try assumption;
      (* otherwise, add another conjunct to the hypothesis and use the first part of it to solve the current goal *)
      refine (fst H) .. ] ];
    [ exact True (* fill the final conjunct with True *)
    | repeat apply pair; try exact I .. ].
```

Then you can invoke it as `distinct_subgoals_tactical ltac:(<apply tactic here>)`